# I moved my PHP file to a subfolder and it's not working anymore

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, action, subdirectory

Below is a document tree of the folders on my website. In my html form the action attribute holds this value: delete_post.php. When I changed the action to /do/delete_post/index.php it wouldn't work. How could I change this: do/delete_post/index.php or something else to make it work?
[image]

The index.php file is shown below:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']) || empty($_POST['id'])) 
  {
  header( "Location: /" );
  die();
  }
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/db.php')
$stmt2 = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = ?');
if (!$stmt2->execute(array($_POST['id'])))
  {
  print_r($stmt2->errorInfo());
  die();
  }
header( "Location: /" );

?>
```

When I make an ajax request using jquery in php with the following page the index.php fails to delete the post.

Comment: How does it not work? What error do you get when you send the form? What URL do you end up at exactly?

Comment: i'm using ajax (I cant really see the errors unless I use a packet sniffer.)

Comment: @inquisitive why can't you use Firebug's "Net" tab? Much better than guessing, which is all we can do at this stage.

Comment: I have firebug lite but not firebug. and i don't see a net tab.

Comment: http://getfirebug.com/network

Answer (score 0):

can you navigate to /do/delete_post/index.php without any errors (visible or in php error_log)?

i suspect either:

include_path issues

-or-

some url rewriting with .htaccess. is there a .htaccess file in the root dir?

Answer (score 0):

Do you include any files within your workflow?

If you use relative paths, they are always relative to the current working directory (CWD) which is usually the directory where your executing script is.

If you change `delete_post.php`'s folder and you are including a script which includes other scripts with relative paths, these scripts will fail to load as the CWD will be different.

So, instead of using relative paths, use the following:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/data.inc.php';
```

Comment: I think you're right. Inside my index.php I have this line of code (shown below) that is supposed to include a file that is in root/includes/db.php how could I change the line of php below to resolve my issue? require_once('/includes/db.php');

Comment: @inquisitive_web_developer: No, because `/includes/db.php` is an absolute path starting at the root of your Linux install... I doubt your file resolves there... However, you can change it to `require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/db.php')`.

Comment: I tried what you said. It still doesn't work. I added the source of index.php in the question if that helps.

Comment: @inquisitive_web_developer: Well, if you do move the file, you need to update the `require_once` in that file to `require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../includes/db.php')`